# How to properly render latin2 characters using google-font?

Tags: google-font-api

I have to render slavic letters (đ, č, ć, ...) with google-font, but what I get is always degraded rendering using alternative font, so the words are really ugly...

How could I encode these letters to have proper rendering? I have tried a few entities without success.

Comment: Do you have an example of the problem? I looked at the google font library and it seems like the characters that you wrote prints out fine.

The page i viewed was: http://www.google.com/fonts and in the Preview Text field I put in the characters you mentioned. Most fonts printed them just fine.

Comment: if it helps, the character encoding is ISO-8859-2

Comment: are you using latin or latin extended? latin extended is the one to go for

Comment: In fact, I was using UTF-8... So which alias should I use for extended latin? ISO-8859-2?

Comment: The strange thing is that I have expected rendering for a few letters in UTF-8 (e.g: č, š), but not for others (e.g: đ). That's quite confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it: the letters not rendered were not defined in the font... That's kind of misleading when *almost* all expected letters are defined, but others are missing!

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if still relevant, but you need to add `&subset=all` to the URL with which you load the font. For example:

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic&subset=all" 
       rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```